# How to check if the Default Value Constraint exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server 2008. I need to find if default value constraint does not exist then create it. Here is what I have tried.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME ='MyConstraint'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [XX] ADD  CONSTRAINT [MyConstraint]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [XXXX]
END
GO
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
if not exists (
    select *
      from sys.all_columns c
      join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
      join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
      join sys.default_constraints d on c.default_object_id = d.object_id
    where t.name = 'table'
      and c.name = 'column'
      and s.name = 'schema')
  ....
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, it is recommended to use the catalog views from the `sys` schema - `sys.columns`, `sys.tables`  - instead of `sysobjects` etc. Those will be removed from a future version of SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s I have changed the code, but `sysobjects` etc compatibility views are going to be around for a **long** time yet, at least past the next version of SQL Server. _The following SQL Server Database Engine features are supported in the **next** version of SQL Server, but will be removed in a later version. The specific version of SQL Server has not been determined._ [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - Your link does include as its third sentence "Deprecated features should not be used in new applications."

Answer (score 31):

I find this to be easier:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SchemaName.MyConstraint', 'D') IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- create it here
END
```

Comment: Even thought my default constraint definitely exists, `OBJECT_ID` returns null for it.

Comment: It migt not work if user doesn't have permission to view the object.

Answer (score 11):

I was a bit puzzled as to why this simple task was so complicated. In my case, I don't have constraint names - only table and column names. I want to check if they already have a default before trying to add one.

After a bit more digging, I came up with this:

```
IF (SELECT Column_Default FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MY_COLUMN') is NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE]
    ADD DEFAULT ('') FOR [MY_COLUMN]
END
GO
```

I have to implement this in a ginormous boilerplate script, so the shorter the better.

Comment: I don't have names for column defaults either so this approach worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.default_constraints where name = 'SchemaName.MyConstraint')
begin
  -- create it here
end
```

Comment: Please add some explanations, avoid code only answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This actually doesn't work if you search the object including the schema

Answer (score 1):

Search the system table where the default costraints of the database are stored, **without the schema name**:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.default_constraints WHERE [name] = 'MyConstraint')
    print 'Costraint exists!';
ELSE
    print 'Costraint doesn''t exist!';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on SQL Server 2016.

Assuming I have a table named MY_TABLE and a column MY_COLIUMN.
I would like to add a constrain (default to '-1' ) on  MY_COLIUMN that need to add the constrain on.

```
/* Test for the specific column */
IF EXISTS (select 1 from sys.all_columns c where c.object_id= OBJECT_ID(N'MY_TABLE') and c.name='MY_COLIUMN')
BEGIN
  /* Add default if not exits */
  IF NOT EXISTS (
      select 1 from sys.default_constraints c where c.object_id = 
      (
        select default_object_id from sys.all_columns c where c.object_id =  OBJECT_ID(N'MY_TABLE') and c.name='MY_COLIUMN'
        )
     )
  BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
    ADD DEFAULT '-1' FOR MY_COLIUMN;
  END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following in the past:

```
DECLARE @default sysname
SELECT @default = object_name( cdefault ) FROM syscolumns WHERE id = object_id( 'DBO.TABLE' ) AND name = 'COLUMN'
IF ( not @default is null )
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming to the party late here, but I am a big fan of OBJECTPROPERTY.  Here is how to set a default of 1 on a column if the default does not yet exist.

```
IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('My_constraint_name'),'CnstIsColumn') IS NULL
ALTER TABLE Mytable ADD  CONSTRAINT [MY_constraint_name] DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [My_column_name]
```